# R: Create a new column with multiple categories(levels) based on the critera of two other columns

Tags: r, calculated-columns

my data looks like the following

```
> head(CPUE)
    Lon.rect Lat.rect         q1          q4
    1     13.5    54.25  0.1930234  1.76096260
    2     13.5    54.75 11.6866331 19.06265440
    3     13.5    55.25 24.2532215 33.64530930
    4     13.5    55.75  0.2113688  0.05731537
    5     14.5    54.25  2.5600818  8.72482876
    6     14.5    54.75 85.8657297 34.08524869
```

Now, what I would like to do is create a new column, with multiple categories (levels) based on a combination of the data from subsets "Lon.rect" & "Lat.rect". I would like to name the categories something different, based on what data is in each column. e.g. for Lon.rect = 13.5, Lat.rect = 54.25, the category name in the new column would be "1A", while in row two the category would be "1B", because Lat.rect has contains different data. Row 5 would be "2A", and so on.

`"Lon.rect"` & `"Lat.rect"` contain coordinates (if that matters to anyone) and have several more combinations. From Lot 13.5 to 22.5 and Lat 54.25 to 58.75.

I created a new column called "subdiv" by:

```
CPUE["subdiv"] <- NA
```

Whole dataset now looks:

```
   > head(CPUE)
      Lon.rect Lat.rect         q1          q4 subdiv
    1     13.5    54.25  0.1930234  1.76096260     NA
    2     13.5    54.75 11.6866331 19.06265440     NA
    3     13.5    55.25 24.2532215 33.64530930     NA
    4     13.5    55.75  0.2113688  0.05731537     NA
    5     14.5    54.25  2.5600818  8.72482876     NA
    6     14.5    54.75 85.8657297 34.08524869     NA
```

I know I could enter everything like below, but that would take ages and since it's a lot of data.

```
CPUE$subdiv[CPUE$Lon.rect>=13 & CPUE$Lon.rect<=14 & CPUE$Lat.rect>=54.0 & CPUE$Lat.rect<=54.5] <- "1A"
CPUE$subdiv[CPUE$Lon.rect>=13 & CPUE$Lon.rect<=14 & CPUE$Lat.rect>=54.5 & CPUE$Lat.rect<=55.0] <- "1B"
CPUE$subdiv[CPUE$Lon.rect>=13 & CPUE$Lon.rect<=14 & CPUE$Lat.rect>=55.0 & CPUE$Lat.rect<=55.5] <- "1C"
```

I hope I made my description quite clear, otherwise don't hesitate to contact me!
If anyone has a good solution to any of the steps, please write back!
Thanks!
/Filip

#### **EDIT:**

**Further information about my problem**

The names for the columns above; "1A", "1B" and "2A", are just examples to make clear how I want the relation the the source columns to be, I really want to name them something else, however I got some nice help below if someone is interested of this.

In my case I would like to name `Lat.rect` column after integers starting at 37. The  `Lon.rect` would be a bit trickier. This name is composed of one letter and one number, starting at G3 (in this case). The highest number for each letter would be 9, and then next letter starts at 0, so the next name after G9 would be H0.

If it helps, I would not need a script to make this combination for the whole alphabet. The minimum possible combination (of all my data sets, not needed currently) are F9, and maximum H9.

I would also like to have the lat name first and lon name second. If it would be easier to first swap location of the column in the data.frame to then create the name, this would be fine.

The finished combination of the first row would be "37G3", and then the second row "38G3". Row 5 would be "37G4".

If anyone would be able to help me with this second part, I would be grateful!

Comment: Instead of naming a new column you can use `paste` and `factor`.  `with(CPUE, factor(paste(Lon.rect, Lat.rect)))`.  If you're trying to first "bucketize" your numeric coordinates, use `cut`.

Comment: Hi, the thing is that I don't want to name the categories in the new column the same as the source columns. I want to give them a different name, but still based on the levels of the source.
Thanks though! This could be helpful in other cases.

I didn't really get the `cut` function, sorry. I'm a newbie. I just got the reply "'x' must be numeric".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, in case your data is not sorted like this (by `lon` and then by `lat`) and you want `subdiv` to include all `levels` of `lot` and `lan`, you could:

```
    CPUE <- data.frame(lon = as.vector(replicate(4, sample(13.5:22.5, 10, T))),
                       lat = as.vector(replicate(4, sample(seq(54, 56.25, 0.25), 10, T))))

    num <- findInterval(CPUE$lon, sort(unique(CPUE$lon)))
    lett <- findInterval(CPUE$lat, sort(unique(CPUE$lat)))

    CPUE$subdiv <- paste(num, LETTERS[lett], sep = "")

    CPUE
        lon   lat subdiv
    1  13.5 54.50     1C #this is the first possible "lon" and the third possible "lat"
    2  15.5 54.50     3C
    3  20.5 55.25     8F #this is the eigth possible "lon" and the sixth possible "lat"
    4  19.5 54.00     7A
    5  16.5 55.75     4H
```

NOTE: This approach won't work if (1) you don't want to include all possible levels of "lon" and "lat", **and** (2) your data is not sorted as posted.

**EDIT**

Maybe something like this?:

```
    CPUE <- data.frame(lon = sort(rep(13.5:22.5, 13)),
                       lat = rep(seq(54.25, 60.25, 0.5), 10))

    lat_names <- findInterval(CPUE$lat, sort(unique(CPUE$lat))) + 36

    lon_names <- as.vector(sapply(LETTERS, paste, 0:9, sep = ""))
    lon_names <- lon_names[match("G3", lon_names):length(lon_names)]
    lon_names <- lon_names[findInterval(CPUE$lon, sort(unique(CPUE$lon)))]

    CPUE$subdiv <- paste(lat_names, lon_names, sep = "")

    > CPUE
         lon   lat subdiv
    1   13.5 54.25   37G3
    2   13.5 54.75   38G3
    3   13.5 55.25   39G3
    4   13.5 55.75   40G3
    5   13.5 56.25   41G3
    6   13.5 56.75   42G3
    7   13.5 57.25   43G3
    8   13.5 57.75   44G3
    9   13.5 58.25   45G3
    10  13.5 58.75   46G3
    11  13.5 59.25   47G3
    12  13.5 59.75   48G3
    13  13.5 60.25   49G3
    14  14.5 54.25   37G4
    15  14.5 54.75   38G4
    16  14.5 55.25   39G4
    17  14.5 55.75   40G4
    18  14.5 56.25   41G4
    19  14.5 56.75   42G4
    20  14.5 57.25   43G4
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Alt1 seems to change the value of my lon&lat, don't really know why.
Alt 2 would be more relevant in my case. However, the lon really goes to from 13.5 to 22.5, and the lat 54.25 to 60.25. I tried to change it to
`lon = sort(rep(13.5:22.5, 10)),
lat = rep(seq(54.25, 60.25, 0.5), 13))`
Doesn't seem to work though. Get the reply  `arguments imply differing number of rows: 100, 130`.

Now the thing is the the "1A" was only and example of a name, so the pure number and letter won't work in my case. But perhaps a combination and if it's possible to tell R what number/letter to start on...

Comment: I would like to name lon column after integers starting at 37. The lat would be a bit trickier .   This name is composed of one letter and one number, starting at G3 (in this case). The highest number for each letter would be 9, and then next letter starts at 0, so after G9, it would be H0. Would you now how to do this? Thanks for all the help. Sorry, that I can't give your answer a bump up, my rep is too low. :/
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @balconydorr: I updated my answer. I assumed your data is sorted all the way down like the sample you posted (i.e. assumed that `CPUE` is your actual data). See if it fits you.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick! Thanks a lot! However, I would like to keep my q1 & q4 columns in the new df.

Now I just need to exclude some coordinates, but I guess I can do that by entering !number somewhere, plus some other code.

Comment: @balconydorr: You, just, can run the code to refer to your data and not to the `CPUE` I made. Otherwise, you can add `q1` and `q4` from your `CPUE`. Or you can add my `CPUE$subdiv` to your `CPUE`. So, if you rename your `CPUE` to `oldCPUE` and call `CPUE$q1 <- oldCPUE$q1` (same for `q4`) will do it. But, be careful if rows in your `CPUE` is ifferent than my `CPUE` (you said you have to exclude some coordinates). Better, do the exclusion first, and then do the rest.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I can just add the `q1` & `q4`, though I thought you changed the order of the data with the `sort` function. So I was wondering if I could force the data of `q1` & `q4` to follow `lon` & `lat`. 
But now when I checked again I guess it will look right if I just remove the data points that doesn't really exist. So, yeah, I'll do that first.
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @balconydorr: I used `sort`just to simulate your `CPUE`. I guess if you run the code applied to _your_ data (i.e. istead of `$lat` use `$Lat.rect` etc.) you should get the result you want.

Comment: I did run it with my data, $Lat.rect, but it created new points which didn't exist in my original df. Since, e.g. `Lat.rect` up to 60.25 doesn't exist for all of the Lon.rect. Neither does `Lat.rect` = 54.25. + some other points. I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: It was quite easy to exclude the rows that didn't exist. I used the merge function and defined it by the common rows. (though it created new columns, which I just removed)
 Thanks again.
 `newCPUE2<- merge(CPUE,newCPUE,by.x=c('Lon.rect','Lat.rect'), by.y=c('Lon.rect','Lat.rect'))`

Answer (score 2):

Using `interaction` would be one way to get the `levels` from `unique` combinations of `factors` in your columns. However I use `match` on the first two columns, finding the position of each element in a `table` of the `unique` elements. I can then `paste` these values together and use `as.factor` to coerce to a `factor` variable. I find it makes the renaming of the levels more intuitive for me and it also doesn't rely on the `data.frame` being sorted...

```
a <- match( df[,1] , unique( df[,1] ) )
b <- letters[ match( df[,2] ,  unique( df[,2] ) ) ]

df$new <- as.factor( paste0( a , b ) )
#  Lon.rect Lat.rect         q1          q4 new
#1     13.5    54.25  0.1930234  1.76096260  1a
#2     13.5    54.75 11.6866331 19.06265440  1b
#3     13.5    55.25 24.2532215 33.64530930  1c
#4     13.5    55.75  0.2113688  0.05731537  1d
#5     14.5    54.25  2.5600818  8.72482876  2a
#6     14.5    54.75 85.8657297 34.08524869  2b
```

Comment: I would have used `expand.grid` and merged but that's simpler

Comment: @statquant it just seemed easier to get the labels as desired. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, too bad I already left.

It worked doing what I asked in my question. Now the thing is the the "1A" was only and example of a name, so the pure number and letter won't work in my case. But perhaps a combination and if it's possible to tell R what number/letter to start on.

I would like to name lon column after integers starting at 37. The lat would be a bit trickier. This name is composed of one letter and one number, starting at G3 (in this case). The highest number for each letter would be 9, and then next letter starts at 0, so after G9, it would be H0.

Thanks

Comment: Apparently I can't give you a bump up since I have too low reputation, sorry.